# Terminology for "wrap-around" function ranges

Tags: functions, reference-request

I'm trying to look for literature regarding the formal properties of functions whose output range "wraps around" back to itself in the sense that the lowest possible output is actually more similar to the highest output, thus the "middle" point being the point furthest from the lowest and the highest. The best visualization of this is probably a [color wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_wheel):

[image: By László Németh (Own work) [CC0], via Wikimedia Commons]

A color value can be represented as a triple $(r, g, b)$ in an [RGB color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model), where each value is a natural number (often $0 \leq x \leq 255$), and the lowest and highest values of this range does *not* wrap around.

However, from these RGB values [a hue value can be derived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue#Computing_hue_from_RGB), which is often either a range of $0 \leq x \leq 360$ or $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Hue value *does* "wrap around" in that a hue of 0 is very similar to either 360 or 1 depending on which representation you use. **What is this property called?**

Comment: Maybe you mean "periodic"?  Your two examples are period 360 or period 1.